# Create queue from a many to many relation In SQL

Tags: mysql, queue, sql-order-by

My relations are defined like this in ActiveRecord

```rb
class Developer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :developers_code_reviews
  has_many :code_reviews, through: :developers_code_reviews
end

class DevelopersCodeReview < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :code_review
  belongs_to :developer
end

class CodeReview < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :developers_code_reviews
  has_many :developers, through: :developers_code_reviews
end
```

So a developer has many code reviews and a code review has many developers. This works through this developers_code_reviews table.

What I want is querying MySQL to have a developer queue for code reviews. For example, if no code reviews are created yet and we have dev1, dev2, dev3. If dev1 gets a code review, then dev2 or dev3 should have the next one. If the next code review is given to dev2 and dev3, the next code review should be given to dev1.

I found a good StackOverflow answer which brought me there:

```sql
SELECT developer_id
FROM developers_code_reviews
GROUP BY developer_id
ORDER BY max(updated_at) ASC
```

The problem is that I have only developer ids from the table `developers_code_reviews` and I want `developers`, not `developers_code_reviews`.

So I found some documentation on sub queries and found this query which runs:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM developers
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT developer_id
  FROM developers_code_reviews
  GROUP BY developer_id
  ORDER BY max(updated_at) ASC
)
```

But it doesn't keep the ordering from `IN` query. Does somebody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did You try it with inner join instead of an in  clause

Like

```
SELECT *
FROM developers d inner Join ( SELECT developer_id,max(updated_at) maxupdt
  FROM developers_code_reviews
  GROUP BY developer_id)  dcr ON d.id=dcr.developer_id
ORDER BY maxupdt
```

Ordering subquerys is only is  pnly necessary in conjunction  with LIMIT

Comment: Actually there's a small issue with it but it wasn't included in my final question. This query doesn't include developers that don't have a code review already. Let's say I add a new developer to the DB, it won't be in the queue. Do you know how to solve this? I believe that a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` works but I can't explain it.

Comment: Left Join would show also ''all developers* the are **not** in the  developers_code_reviews. So it is a good idea, if you need it.